# C to R : create a vector of list

Tags: c, r

I am writing an R package, and want to create a vecor of lists :
I make the following :

```
int dim = 5;
SEXP root;
PROTECT(root=allocVector(VECSXP,dim));
for(int i=0;i<dim;i++)
{
    SEXP(coerceVector(root))[i] = list1(allocVector(REALSXP, 1));
}
// every list will be appended after
//I have not any means to know its length in advanc
```

Unfortunately, this code does not even compile.
Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you meant *pairlist* and not *list* the proper code would look more like

```
int dim = 5;
SEXP root = PROTECT(allocVector(VECSXP, dim));
for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
    SET_VECTOR_ELT(root, i, list1(allocVector(REALSXP, 1)));
```

I'm not sure if that's what you intended, but that is equivalent to:

```
> root = list(pairlist(NA_real_), pairlist(NA_real_), pairlist(NA_real_), pairlist(NA_real_), pairlist(NA_real_))
> str(root)
List of 5
 $ :Dotted pair list of 1
  ..$ : num NA
 $ :Dotted pair list of 1
  ..$ : num NA
 $ :Dotted pair list of 1
  ..$ : num NA
 $ :Dotted pair list of 1
  ..$ : num NA
 $ :Dotted pair list of 1
  ..$ : num NA
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is exactly what I want. However, accessing the pair lists is still a problem for me. I want for example to access the first element of the third list in my vector of lists. I try : CAR(root[2]) but it does not work. By analogy with your code, I tried CAR(GET_VECTOR_ELT(root,2)) but it does not work : GET_VECTOR_ELT is not defined.

Comment: Please consider reading R-exts - it does help ;). What you're looking for is `VECTOR_ELT`

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I was not able to find it by myself, even if I looked in writing R-exts (after having your response, I searched for VECTOR_ELT and did not find it). You saved me a lot of time and effort, thanks again

Comment: (You must be looking at something wrong -- VECTOR_ELT is mentioned many times ... see http://r.research.att.com/man/R-exts.html for example)

Comment: In fact!! Thanks a lot. That will help me a lot